# What is the meaning of the y axis in distribution plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have made an distributional plot but i dont know what the y axis is showing. The x axis has very low numbers from 0 to 0.0001.

Part of my code:

```
lm=LinearRegression()
x=df[['horsepower']]
y=df['price']
lm.fit(x, y)
Yhat=lm.predict(x)
ax1=sns.distplot(df['price'],hist=False,color='r',label='AV')
sns.distplot(Yhat,hist=False,color='b',label='P',ax=ax1)

plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfGlQ.png)

Comment: It is a KDE plot. The y axis is the "density" at the given X. or at least an estimation of it. You should only really think of relative to other y-values. The value itself isn't going to be of much help

Comment: So does the density show me how close my x values are in a certain part of the x axis?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "how close your x values are". If you mean the x values between the AV and P plot, then you can interpret the graph as: Up until about 1000, AV and P have similar frequencies of values. After that, less so. And AV has a much higher frequency of values around 3000-4000.